# Scattering overlapping points using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point, overlapping-features

I am working with a series of points that are located at the same location.

Can I scatter these point so that it is possible to visualize them as I zoom in?

Unfortunately, they don't have any element in common in the Attribute Table.

I am using ArcGIS Desktop.

Comment: Try searching on disperse rather than scatter.

Comment: Here is a link to the help tool for disperse.   http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/cartography-toolbox/disperse-markers.htm

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have just the basic Desktop license. Does it work with my license?